# PHP echo's javascript as text?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to echo some javascript but it is making it as text, it works fine on my test page but when I add it to wordpress it turns it into text. But I have another part where the script runs fine.

```
    echo ' 
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: \'short_name\',
  route: \'long_name\',
  locality: \'long_name\',
  administrative_area_level_1: \'short_name\',
  country: \'long_name\',
  postal_code: \'short_name\'
};

function initialize() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
  // to geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById(\'autocomplete\')),
      { types: [\'geocode\'] });
  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
  // populate the address fields in the form.
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, \'place_changed\', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = \'\';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}
// [END region_fillform]

if (typeof jQuery != \'undefined\') {

    alert("jQuery library is loaded!");

}else{

    alert("jQuery library is not found!");

}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {initialize();});

    </script>
   <style>

      #autocomplete {
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 350px;
      }

    </style>

  </head>

  <div>

';
```

I know that the code works, just that the echo doesn't. Please help.

Sorry for the sloppy code :[

Output :

```
<style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&#038;sensor=false&#038;libraries=places"></script><br />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script><br />
   <script>
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.</p>
<p>var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};</p>
<p>function initialize() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
  // to geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      { types: ['geocode'] });
  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
  // populate the address fields in the form.
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
}</p>
<p>// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();</p>
<p>  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }</p>
<p>  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}
// [END region_fillform]</p>
<p>if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {</p>
<p>    alert("jQuery library is loaded!");</p>
<p>}else{</p>
<p>    alert("jQuery library is not found!");</p>
<p>}</p>
<p>jQuery(document).ready(function () {initialize();});</p>
<p>    </script></p>
<style>
<p>      #autocomplete {
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 350px;
      }</p>
</style>
```

Comment: Are you adding the code in the CMS editor or to a template?

Comment: I am including it, using a plugin, I have used it before and it worked great.

Comment: does php know how to handle strings with carriage returns in single quotes?

Comment: JavaScript _is_ text - if PHP is rendering it as text, that is what you want. I'm trying to work out what the problem is here. I'd advise you not to trap JavaScript inside PHP strings this way (except where bits really are dynamic) - it is better to put them in a PHP file and `include` them.

Comment: If I recall correctly, Wordpress has a global output buffer where it takes care of escaping things for use in HTML.  Wordpress is trying to prevent you from creating a security nightmare.

Comment: put all that in a PHP file by itself without the echo and use this  ---  include 'myfile.php';   ---   place that to the position you want that html to appear -- may not work in word press

Comment: It ran before in the same age that is being included using - `echo "
                <script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert('Please fill out all required fields');
                </script>";`

Comment: Hmm, just seen your question update - paragraphs! Is it possible to add this JS to your theme? Failing that, there's probably a hook you can register that you can use to call a function that does the `include` I recommended earlier.

Comment: Just replace your single quotes with double quotes ' -> ".  echo " msg here ";

Comment: And the <stlye> is also coming out as text

Comment: @boyd already tried that

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different ways you can do this.

1) Create a variable heredoc string with all your javascript code in it. Then echo that string. Test to see if that works.

2)The proper way to add scripts to WordPress whether it's a plugin or a theme is to use the wp_enqueue_scripts function ([documentation here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)) and call .

WordPress syntax is as follows:

`<?php wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer ); ?>`

**Step 1:** Place your script into its own js file, for example `your-map-canvas.js`.

**Step 2:** Create a new function.

`function your_map_canvas(){}`

**Step 3:** In the function, create your own handle (can be anything). For this example I'll use `map-canvas`. You will want to make the name unique enough that other plugins/themes won't use the same function and cause conflicts.

**Step 4:** Add the source to the file. If it's a plugin (as you've indicated), use `plugin_dir_path();` ([documentation here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url)) to get dynamically get the path to your plugin folder. $src should look something like this now: `plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'path/in/plugin/folder/to/your-map-canvas.js'`.

This is what you should have so far:

`function your_map_canvas(){
    wp_enqueue_script('map-canvas', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'your-map-canvas.js');
}`

**Step 5:** Call your function with the wp_enqueue_scripts hook

`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_map_canvas' );`

The final code should look something like this:

```
function your_map_canvas(){
    wp_enqueue_script('map-canvas', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'your-map-canvas.js');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_map_canvas' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress converts it to text even when I add it directly into the text editor, because of the spaces and newlines in the code. So I had to use a raw html plugin that allows the code to go through untouched by wordpress. So I added the code in between the plugin snippets and it worked.